# Подключение сетевого моста OVS к ВМ в VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, virtualbox

Задавала этот вопрос на Киберфоруме, но там не ответили, поэтому дублирую сюда.

Есть две машины в VirtualBox.
На одной установлен Open vSwitch.
Создаю на ней коммутатор br0:

```
ovs-vsctl add-br br0
```

Прикручиваю к коммутатору порт vnet0:

```
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 vnet0
```

Ожидаю, что когда зайду в настройки сети второй ВМ и подключу второй адаптер в режиме "Сетевой мост", можно будет выбрать созданный на первой ВМ интерфейс (vnet0), как на [картинке](https://networkstatic.net/wp-content/themes/infocus/cache/openvswitch-VM-640x550.png) из [статьи](https://networkstatic.net/open-vswitch-on-virtualbox/), по которой пытаюсь всё это сделать.
Но можно выбрать только стандартные интерфейсы (wlp2s0 и enp1s0), созданные мной не появляются.

Я в этой теме новичок и, возможно, пропускаю что-то важное. Например, в упомянутой статье сказано что-то про образ linux-0.2.img. И в других статьях читала про подключение образа img. Но так и не дошло, где его взять, как подключить.
Работаю в Ubuntu 20.04, на машинах Ubuntu Server той же версии.

Comment: `Есть две машины в VirtualBox. На одной установлен Open vSwitch.` - то есть вы делаете switch *внутри* виртуалки, но удивляетесь почему его не видно на хост-системе?

Comment: @Мелкий, я отсылку оценил.

Comment: @donRumata, отсылку?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну загугли "есть 2 стула".

Comment: @donRumata, это уже апофиния...

Comment: нет, это совершенно точно не отсылка.

Comment: @Мелкий Я предупредила, что новичок. Имеете в виду, нужно создать виртуальный адаптер в самой VirtualBox? Я создала, добавила его к машинам как виртуальный адаптер хоста. Он отобразился на них как enp0s8, я добавила его как порт в OVS `ovs-vsctl add-port br0 enp0s8` А дальше что?

Comment: @Мелкий Или OVS надо ставить не на виртуалку?

Comment: @Светлана, в статье предлагается установить Open vSwitch в **хостовую систему**, а не на виртуальную машину... в установке оного на виртульную машину нет ни какого смысла...